# In which managed property is file content (e.g. text content of Word/PDF etc.) stored?

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, crawling, managed-property

I try to demote results in which the search string is "only" inside the content of the file not a metadata (e.g. like "title", "description").

For example a PDF inside SharePoint with the title "xy" is fine (ranking should not be changed) but if "xy" is only inside of the text of the PDF or text of Excel/Word etc. then the ranking of such files should be demoted.

So I try to find out in which managed property the search crawler stores those values? Does anybody know? Is it "Contents"?

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference, the managed property that contains the document's contents is actually "Contents":

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure if you are right. On the page given nothing is written about "Contents" storing the content of documents. I now believe that this information is not stored inside a managed property but inside a completly different full text index.

Answer (score 0):

The managed property is called "body", but it is not query-able by default. To enable querying, you need to modify the "body" managed property in SharePoint's Central Administration. This works in SharePoint 2016.

1. Open up Central Administration
2. Go to: Search Service Application
3. Click "Search Schema" in the left navigation
4. Search for the "Body" managed properly and click on it to edit, you will see: Search Service Application: Edit Managed Property - body
5. Click "Searchable" and "Queryable" and save the changes.
6. Perform a Full Crawl

Now you can used managed property search syntax to return results in the body content of a document stored in SharePoint.