# Crawled Property that stores full contents of a office document

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-property, crawled-property

Just wondering if anyone out there knows of a **SharePoint Online** crawled property that contains the content of an Office document (word, excel etc..)? I am not sure if one actually exists but i know for sure that SharePoint does in fact crawl the entire contents of a document (with some limitations [see here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-limits-for-SharePoint-Online-7c06e9ed-98b6-4304-a900-14773a8fa32f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)).

I know of one crawled property (HitHighlightedSummary) which stores a summary of the contents of a document but I believe this is only limited to 10,000 characters.

There is the following [SO question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160620/in-which-managed-property-is-file-content-e-g-text-content-of-word-pdf-etc-s), but the managed property refered to in the answer does not return the contents of a document, I created a custom managed property with the exact same crawled property mappings as the managed property mentioned in the above SO answer and ensured with was searchable, queryable and retrieveable but to no avail.

**Update: What I am trying to achieve:**

I have a requirement where I need to display/highlight the location in a document where keywords used in the search query by the user appear.

Search does a good job in retrieving all documents that contain the keyword or phrase that a user searches for, however it does not show where in the document those keywords, phrases are found it only highlight them if they are found in the ‘HitHighlight Summary' managed property and that only contains 10,000 characters of the document, if the keyword or phrase that was searched for is beyond those 10,000 characters it will still return the document as a result in the search but will not highlight where in the document it was found.

I need to be able to locate where in a document the keyword was found, I was hoping that if I could find a managed property that contains the whole contents of the document I would be able to build a custom Display Template that could highlight those values, but I am not having any luck in finding where SharePoint stores the whole content of a document for search purposes. SharePoint does crawl the entire document (see link above) and the fact that I can search for a keyword or phrase in document that is not included in the summary and it still gets returned means that Search somehow has the whole document content stored somewhere to be able to do a quick search against it content.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The entire document is not stored in the index, only a summary. You can investigate both `Body` and `Contents` as they also contain a summary based on the content type crawled, but will not be the whole document.

Tell us what you are trying to do and maybe there is a solution that does not require a Managed Property.

Comment: I have updated my answer with what I am trying to achieve, I have looked at other crawled/managed properties but none have had what I want.